# jBPM Repositories disappear after Wildfly restart

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jbpm, wildfly-9

Pardon if I can't give more pointers, but I'm really a noob at wildfly. I'm using version 9.0.2.

I have deployed jbpm-console, drools, and dashboard - no problems here. I restart wildfly using the jboss CLI, and when I login again, the repositories won't appear in the web interface or on disk (atleast nothing that grepping or find will show).

I'm using the H2 database. I'm not even sure where to look, does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough reading through the docs, it would seem that it's necessary to configure jBPM to persist. From the docs:

"By default, the engine does not save runtime data persistently. This means you can use the engine completely without persistence (so not even requiring an in memory database) if necessary, for example for performance reasons, or when you would like to manage persistence yourself. It is, however, possible to configure the engine to do use persistence by configuring it to do so. This usually requires adding the necessary dependencies, configuring a datasource and creating the engine with persistence configured."

https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.3/userguide/ch.core-persistence.html